# How to check if EPIserver.Core.ContentReference is true or contains something?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, episerver

We have a block in our EPIserver website called KeyVisualBlock. This is basically the header section of our pages consisting of things like a hero image, page title.

Our users would like to be able to insert a form into this area of the page.

So I have modified our Model KeyVisualBlock.cs to include the ability to select a form by adding:

```
[CultureSpecific]
[Display(Order = 90,
GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content)]
[AllowedTypes(typeof(FormContainerBlock))]
public virtual ContentReference ContactForm { get; set; }
```

Now I would like to check if this field contains a form and then display the form in our view. So in our View I am trying to do something like this:

```
@{ 
    if (Model.CurrentKeyVisualBlock.ContactForm) {
        // do something.
    }
}
```

But Visual Studio informs me that:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'EPIserver.Core.ContentReference' to
>   type 'bool'

What is the preferred way to check this?

Answer (score 4):

You can check whether the content reference is set like this:

```
if (!ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CurrentKeyVisualBlock.ContactForm))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

But keep in mind that even though the content reference isn't null the content it refers to might not exist. To be really sure you need to actually load the content, preferably like this:

```
// Constructor injected IContentRespository into field contentRepository.
if (this.contentRepository.TryGet<FormContainerBlock>(Model.CurrentKeyVisualBlock.ContactForm, out var formContainerBlock))
{
}
```